# Upgrading a project from older version of YII

Tags: php, yii

I have a project which is made on an older version of YII framework. But while working further on this project I feel that the old way of coding was too time consuming.

I need to make some huge upgrades and add features to the project.

What am I suppose to do if I have a lot of time on the project. Shall I start it from scratch on a latest version of YII or any other best PHP frameworks. Or shall I update on the same. The current version of the application is stable.

Comment: If you're already comfortable with Yii, then Yii2 is a really good framework to upgrade to, however you would need to completely move over, AFAIK there is no migration path from Yii to Yii2.

Comment: That's the difficulty I am facing. On top of that the project was written 5 years ago. With all the old ways of coding which makes things more time consuming to develop further.

Comment: I have faced the same thing and decided to move to Yii2. As Jay said it is not backward compatible and not all of the third party components were ported to Yii2. A good starting point can be a tutorial from someone who has done this (and took the time to write a blog post) : http://www.folio3.com/blog/upgrading-from-php-yii-1-x-to-yii2/